# What is best directory for storing uploaded images from my website in linux

Tags: linux, web-server, directory, upload, images

i am building a webpage where a the user can upload images. i am going to use the file-system to store my images. i was wondering what is the best directory to hold such data? is it "var" directory? "srv" directory? or other?

Comment: Store them on a separate partition, so that if users aggressively upload images, they can't fill the system disk(s) and cause problems for other services. Quota them per user, so one user can't fill the entire image upload space and cause a denial of service for other user uploads.

Comment: It would be a more on-topic question for ServerFault if you asked it as "what factors should I consider when choosing a folder?", rather than "which folder should I use?". Then there could be good answers like "consider packag updates overwriting the folders", "consider the filesystem standard location guides", and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer on:[Unix & Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233343/what-is-best-directory-for-storing-uploaded-files-images-from-my-website)
As @jlliagre pointed out, the best location for a persistent uploaded files is under "/srv/" directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's totally up to you. Maybe store them in a directory below your web site's root?